# Trac: "opened" time display format on ticket screen

Tags: trac

Is it possible to change the way trac displays "opened" and "last modified" times on the ticket screen?

I often need to know the exact date something happened on our system. I can find the relevant ticket by searching for keywords. Then I would like to simply open the ticket and see the exact date instead of "opened 1 month ago" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover the mouse over the text "opened 1 month ago" and it will display the exact date in tooltip.